# i would know what is this recursive function

Tags: function, recursion

I would understand in relation of my script what is the correspondent mathematical function: (x must be an integer)

```
def f(x):
    if x==0:
        return -1
    elif x==1:
        return -1
    else:
        return f(x-1)*f(x-2)
```

Comment: This does not look like a recursive function ...

Comment: There's no recursion here.

Comment: I correct my script because I realize that was wrong, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Recursive function - it's the one which implementation references itself. To calculate a final result it will call it self with different parameter values.

In your case there is no recursion

Comment: I correct my script because I realize that was wrong, sorry –

Answer (score 0):

This is not a recursive function, there is no call to int within int itself. This would just calculate (x-1)*(x-2) unless x is 0 or 1.

Comment: I correct my script because I realize that was wrong, sorry –